# Grid Load With Specific,Conditional Content

Tags: c#, .net, sql, winforms, linq

I have following database table>>

```
   (string)   (float)     (float)       (float)
    TradeNo | Buy_Sell | Trade_Qty | Market_Price

    205412     1           50            300   

    205487     2           30            350 

    208754     1           20            200
```

In this table there is column Buy_Sell. Buy=1 , Sell =2

When I bind the grid, values are showing as it is.

But , I wanted to show them in grid as >

```
TradeNo | Buy_Sell | Trade_Qty | Market_Price

205412     Buy           50            300   

205487     Sell          30            350 

205487     Buy           20            200
```

How can i do that?

I have simply bound the grid with following code>

```
try
{
    con.Open();
    da = new SqlDataAdapter("select ..., 
                TradeNo, Buy_Sell, TradeQty, MarketPrice", con);
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    da.Fill(ds);
    // gvTradeFile.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
    gvTradeFile.DataSource = ds.Tables[0].AsEnumerable()
        .Select(d => new
        {
            TradeNo = d.Field<string>("TradeNo"),
            Buy_Sell = d.Field<float>("Buy_Sell") == 1 ? "Buy" : "Sell",
            TradeQty = d.Field<float>("TradeQty"),
            Market_Price = d.Field<float>("MarketPrice")
        });             
 }
 catch (Exception ex)
 {
     MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
 }
```

This code is not giving me any exception, but also not showing me result in grid.

Is there any way other than LINQ query to have result like this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Select` method returns an `IQueryable` result. This is not sufficient for the data binding to work correctly, since `DataSource` property awaits object of `IList`, `IListSource`, `IBindingList` or `IBindingListView`.

The resolution is simple enough though - just convert your result data set to something that implements one of these interafces, for example just calling `ToList`:

```
.Select(d => new {...}).ToList();
```

Comment: Its giving me exception , "Specified Cast Not Valid"

Comment: @PakkPuneriPorag, then there is an invalid type cast somewhere. Most likely there is something wrong inside the select, the way you are casting your columns to CLR types. What are the data types in the DB of the columns your are using?

Comment: I have edited table with datatypes i have used. Please have a look at it.

Comment: Ok fine. I understood, since i was trying to show it as "Buy" and "Sell" and datatype was float. I changed it to nvarchar(50) and made it as <string> and it worked. Thanx.

Answer (score 0):

You need to convert your query back to a DataView using [AsDataView()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/bb907985.aspx).  e.g.

```
.Select(d => new
{
    TradeNo = d.Field<string>("TradeNo"),
    Buy_Sell = d.Field<float>("Buy_Sell") == 1 ? "Buy" : "Sell",
    TradeQty = d.Field<float>("TradeQty"),
    Market_Price = d.Field<float>("MarketPrice")
})
.AsDataView();
```